# Redux FlatList: update partially data

Tags: react-native, redux, immutability, reducers, react-native-flatlist

how can I partially update my data in redux using Flatlist and React-Native?
I have tried several 'immutable' libraries but nothing worked perfectly.

Redux Store:

```
FlatListData: [ { a: 1, aa: 11 }, { b: 2, bb: 22 }, { c: 3, cc: 33 }, { d: 4, dd: 44 }, ];
```

New data downloaded:

```
updatedData: [ { b: 2, bb: 44 }, { c: 6, cc: 33 }, { e: 8, ee: 90 }, ];
```

How should the reducer look like?

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { FlatListData: [ { a: 1, aa: 11 }, { b: 2, bb: 22 } ] };

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE_RATE:
          return {
            ...state,
            FlatListData: ???   <---
           };
          }}
```

Thanks a lot for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is about merging the two (old and new) you can spread the array and add the updated list to it as follows:

```
export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_RATE:
      return {
        ...state,
        FlatListData: [
          ...state.FlatListData,
          ...action.updatedData,
        ],
      };
  }
}
```

If you need to replace existing values, you need a common key (some id) to identify existing records and filter them. Assuming your array objects have an id:

```
export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_RATE:
      return {
        ...state,
        FlatListData: [
          ...state.FlatListData.filter((x) => 
            !action.updatedData.find((y) => y.id === x.id)),
          ...action.updatedData,
        ],
      };
  }
}
```